# Iterate array and form another format or array

Tags: javascript, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This is my array

```
Arrdata = [{fdata:[], title:"1","desc":""}, {fdata:[], title:"2",,"desc":""}]
```

I want to create another as output like this..

```
steps = [
  { name: Arrdata.title[0], component: Arrdata.fdata[0],
  { name: Arrdata.title[1]", component: Arrdata.fdata[1] },
]
```

would appreciate your help.

Comment: Removed React from title & tags - this is just a pure javascript question :-)

Comment: did you mean to do `steps = [
  { name: Arrdata[0].title, component: Arrdata[0].fdata },
  { name: Arrdata[1].title, component: Arrdata[1].fdata }
]` to get `[
  { name: "1", component: [] },
  { name: "2", component: [] }
]`?

Answer (score 0):

You want the `.map` function of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform it from one shape to another

```
steps = Arrdata.map(item => ({ name: item.title, component: item.fdata }))
```